# not able to get data.or getting two time same data in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i am having in table view which will display the data from one url.But when i open first time.I am seeing two times same data or some time no data are showing in my table view.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {





    // check the current view controller
    weak var currentViewController: UIViewController?

    // show the location
    @IBOutlet weak var LocationLabel: UILabel!

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet var TypeLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var TableViewList: UITableView!



    var startLocation: CLLocation!


    var NewCurrentLatitude: Double!

    var NewCurrentLongitude: Double!

    var BTdata = BTData?()

    var BTypeId : String?

    // array to store the value from json
    var arrDict = [Businessdata]()


    var selectedIndex:NSIndexPath?

    override func viewDidLoad() {


        super.viewDidLoad()

        isSearching = false;

        locationManager.delegate = self

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()



        startLocation = nil


        // nib for custom cell (table view)
        let nib = UINib(nibName:"customCell", bundle: nil)
        TableViewList.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

       // LoadBusinesses()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        self.TypeLabel.text = BTdata?.BTNames
        self.BTypeId = BTdata?.BTIds
         locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    // current location
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate;
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks!.count > 0
            {
                let pm : CLPlacemark = placemarks![0]
                //stop updating location to save battery life

                let locality = (pm.locality != nil) ? pm.locality : ""

                let state = pm.administrativeArea

                let countryCode = pm.ISOcountryCode



                if(countryCode == "CAN")
                {
                    self.LocationLabel.text = "in "+locality!+", "+state!

                    self.NewCurrentLongitude = location.longitude;

                    self.NewCurrentLatitude = location.latitude;

                }
                else
                {
                    self.LocationLabel.text = "in Toronto, ON"

                    self.NewCurrentLatitude = 43.761539;

                    self.NewCurrentLongitude = -79.411079;

                    print("Manual location Label.")
                }

                self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

            }
            else
            {
                print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
             self.LoadBusinesses()

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(self.NewCurrentLongitude, forKey: "UserLongitude")

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(self.NewCurrentLatitude, forKey: "UserLatitude")

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


        })




    }


    // location load failure
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
        print("Error while updating location " + error.localizedDescription)
    }






    // web services method
    func LoadBusinesses()
    {
        print("Inside Load Business")

        let token = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("access_token") as! String

        let headers = ["x-access-token": token]

        var StringUrl:String = "http:some url"

        StringUrl += "?lat=\(self.NewCurrentLatitude)"

        StringUrl += "&long=\(self.NewCurrentLongitude)"

        print(StringUrl)

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: StringUrl)!,
                                          cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print(error)
            }
            else
            {

                    if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])) as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        let success = json["success"] as? Int

                        if (success == 1)
                        {
                            if let reposArray = json["data"] as? [NSDictionary]
                            {
                                 self.arrDict.removeAll()
                                for item in reposArray
                                {
                                    let itemObj = item as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

                                    let b_type = itemObj!["business_type"]

                                    // taxis type
                                    if (b_type as? String == self.BTypeId)
                                    {
                                    self.arrDict.append(Businessdata(json:item))
                                    print("load data")


                                    }

                                }
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{


                                    self.TableViewList.reloadData()

                                     print("load data 1")
                                })

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            let message = json["message"] as? String
                            print(message)
                        }
                    }

            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
          print("load data 2")
        return self.arrDict.count


    }

    // number of rows
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }



    // calling each cell based on tap and users ( premium / non premium )
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
           print("load data 3")

        let cell:customCell = self.TableViewList.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCell

        cell.vendorName.text = arrDict[indexPath.row].BusinessName
        cell.vendorAddress.text = arrDict[indexPath.row].Address
        cell.VendorRating.rating = arrDict[indexPath.row].Rating!

        return cell

    }

    // height of cell based on tap
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        if(isTapped == true && selectedIndex == indexPath)
        {
            return 125.0;
        }

        return 80.0;
    }

    // did select row of table view
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {

        selectedIndex = indexPath;

        isTapped = true;

        print("load data 4")
       // TableViewList.reloadData();

    }


}
```

My full code .In this same problem also i am facing.Showing same data 3 time .In my consloe, the print function is also printing two time.I measn that function executing two times:

```
load data 2
load data 2
load data 2
Manual location Label.
Inside Load Business
http://some url?lat=43.761539&long=-79.411079
load data
load data 2
load data 1
load data 3
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Where did you call `LoadBusinesses()`? I didn't see you called it in this snippet.

Comment: @AlexanderDoloz  i am calling that funcion in my map method.I am using one label to show the user location.So in that i am calling that method.See my update post

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like this. You should reload your tableView after you have parsed the data.

```
if let reposArray = json["data"] as? [NSDictionary] {
    self.arrDict.removeAll()
    for item in reposArray {
        let itemObj = item as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
        let b_type = itemObj!["business_type"]
        // taxis type
        if (b_type as? String == self.BTypeId) {
            self.arrDict.append(Businessdata(json:item))
        }       
    }                   
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
       self.TableViewList.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: no, now same problem.Printing 3 times.one by one same data

Comment: How are you calling the WebService? Can webservice be called again after data has loaded in tableView. Just updated my answer. Try that.

Comment: some times, showing correct data.But some time showing 3 times.Does my web service code is in problem??

Comment: based on user location , i have to display data.So only i called my web service function in my location fetching method

Comment: shall i post my web service code and user location code also.Please help me out.I am struck more here

Comment: i need to send the lat , long of user location with my api.Then only i can see my data in table view. If i omit my user location lat , long then the api will respond to nill.

Comment: Check how many times your  LoadBusinesses() func is getting called and value of self.arrDict in numberOfRows. Also are your updated your array self.arrDict any where else. Also show us your tableView delegates.

Comment: I also updated my console print function .That each statement function executing two times

Comment: Console Print seems to be OK. Please check your webservice response and objects in arrDict. This will give more insight

Comment: i checked that too at starting ,but not able to figure it out

Comment: I just add your line `self.arrDict.removeAll()`First time its ok.But when i see my code again .Its automatically removing why?.If that is fixed then i can solve my problem.Please help me out.How to keep this line as constant.I measn i need to add this line every time or always this line should be in my code.What to do for that??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110300/discussion-between-arun-gupta-and-user5513630).

Comment: my location fetching function is calling many time every time.And some time i am facing that issues.Like showing same data for two or three times